# Firefox extension to automatically and globally cleanup all Google redirects

Tags: firefox

Starting roughly 1-2 years ago, Google made this annoying update where they make every link across all of their products a tracking redirect.

These links are largely broken in my browser. Clicking them creates an empty popup which fails to load the clicked page.

I want an extension that does a global find-and-replace in all web content that autoconverts detected Google redirects into regular links. For example, a redirect link such as https://www.google.com/url?q=http://wikipedia.org/index.php&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=789usg=abCD-EFGH would become http://wikipedia.org/index.php .

I found some redirect removers specific to Google Search while looking for extensions, although no global redirect removers.

Comment: That's not usual if redirects fail. First do full system scan using an [antivirus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_antivirus_software) then [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/) before doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[Don't track me Google](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dont-track-me-google1/)** Firefox extension (also a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-track-me-google/gdbofhhdmcladcmmfjolgndfkpobecpg?hl=en)) should detect those Google redirects. This should work on all Google domains, not just Google Search. [[GitHub page]](https://github.com/Rob--W/dont-track-me-google)

> Removes the annoying link-conversion at Google Search/maps/...
>
> This extension gets rid of Google's ugly (tracking) URL. This speeds
> up loading search results and allows you to normally copy links.
>
> ---
>
> At the Google Search engine, search results are converted to an ugly link upon click. This link enables tracking for Google.
>
> For example, the search entry
>
> - http://www.google.com/
>   (when searching for "Google") will be replaced with:
> - https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=Google&source=web&cd=8&sqi=2&ved=0CFgQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&ei=Ej__TrCkJo2bOrSs2aIE&usg=AFQjCNG5-9Jej-ukVeakTgwonqt2narbYg&sig2=f9f1dWcZoj6ZUC2Zxy9y2g
>
> This addon removes Google's link-conversion/tracking feature. This
> speeds up loading search results and allows you to normally copy
> links.
>
> [image]